# Is [gui] a useful tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

The tag [gui](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gui) is described as

> Use this tag for questions seeking recommendations which have a graphical user interface.

Given the 9600 total questions on SR, only 134 are tagged with it. My personal feeling is that more than 70% of the questions asked here want to have a GUI. There's only 1 follower at the time of writing.

So, is [gui](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gui) really helpful? Should we use it more or should we use it less?

IMHO we could assume that a GUI is wanted as long as it is not tagged [command-line](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-line).

Comment: Good question. I just want to add that beside GUI and command line, many questions deal with libraries and web services (in the WSDL meaning).

Comment: See also: [Dealing with obvious tags](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1147/60)

Comment: It might also be worth considering to "update" its meaning. It could be useful if one looks for "a GUI to X", i.e. just a graphical frontend to something either running from the command line or e.g. as background service. If that's not what we want, I agree: either it's `command-line` tagged, or it wants a GUI (with a few obvious exceptions, eg. database/mail/web servers ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used this tag a few times and I find it personally useful.  As you pointed out, there are quite a few questions that would probably be asking for a GUI. This isn't how I think the tag should be used, though.  Personally, I feel the tag should be used on a question where a Command Line Interface (CLI) software could conceivably be answered.  If the OP doesn't want a CLI, then the tag [gui](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gui) should be used.

For example, if I were to hypothetically ask the question:

> Tool to easily list and edit cron jobs on Linux

Alright, not the best question, but I trying to make a point here.  A CLI could be given as an answer but what if I'm looking for a GUI instead of a CLI?  This is where I would use the tag, [gui](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gui).  Same with CLI, if I wanted a CLI and not a GUI, I would use the tag [cli](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cli).

I don't think we should ever *assume* a specification for a question.  I also think we should keep the tag [gui](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gui) and should be used in the case that without the tag on a question, the question could then be answered by CLI software answers.

Comment: That's a good idea and has also been mentioned by @Izzy in the comments. I suggest we update the tag wiki accordingly.

Comment: @Thomas I agree, we should update the tag wiki.

Comment: there should be an edit in the queue. I proposed "Use this tag for questions seeking recommendations which have a graphical user interface and where a command-line answer would be obvious but does not satisfy your needs."

Comment: Such a question should be edited to put "GUI" in its title, I believe.